# TSQL to count fields and summarize

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

No experiences with this kind of consolidation, but I expect it's routine (hope so) Its counting the columns that throws me.  Actual data is ~20k rows:

Data format:

```
State   Owner   Job1    Job2    Job3    Job4
TN      Joe     123     456             234 
TN      Frank           456     789     
FL      Joe     123     456
FL      Frank   123
```

Results needed:

```
State Owner JobCount
TN  Joe     3
TN  Frank   2
FL  Joe     2
FL  Frank   1
```

And rolled up to Owner

```
Owner   JobCount
Joe     5
Frank   3
```

Comment: do you need both the results?

Comment: This is another reason why it is better to normalize your data. If each job was a row instead of a column this would be painless. The way your table is designed if you need to add Job5 you have to rewrite every query.

Comment: Yeah, I get it.  Not my data, no control there.  And I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your TSQL for result 1

```
SELECT 
    State
    ,Owner 
    ,Sum (
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN Job1 IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END)+
        (CASE 
            WHEN  Job2 IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END) + 
        (CASE 
            WHEN Job3 IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END)+
        (CASE 
            WHEN Job4 IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END))
FROM table
GROUP BY State, OWNER
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm more familiar with this syntax.  I figured out to add the when/then's

Answer (score 2):

I guess PIVOT suites best, since jobs number might increase:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(SELECT [State]
      ,[Owner]
      ,[Job]
      ,[JobN]
FROM (
        SELECT
             [State]
            ,[Owner]
            ,Job1
            ,Job2
            ,Job3
            ,Job4
        FROM #state
     ) AS p
UNPIVOT
(JobN FOR [Job] IN
(Job1,Job2,Job3,Job4)
) AS unpvt)
--SELECT [State], [Owner], COUNT(1) AS JobCount
--FROM cte
--GROUP BY [State], [Owner]
SELECT [Owner], COUNT(1) AS JobCOunt
FROM cte
GROUP BY [Owner]
```

Commented rows are the first query you requested. I've primarily created a temp table #state like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #state
(
    [State] VARCHAR(2)
    ,[Owner] VARCHAR(20)
    ,[Job1] INT
    ,[Job2] INT
    ,[Job3] INT
    ,[Job4] INT
)
```

Comment: Just about to post the same!

Answer (score 1):

For State/Owner

```
select  State, Owner, count(cs.Jobs) as JobCount
from yourtable 
cross apply (values (Job1),(Job2),(Job3),(Job4)) cs (Jobs)
Group By State, Owner
```

Rolled upto Owner

```
select Owner, count(cs.Jobs) as JobCount
from yourtable 
cross apply (values (Job1),(Job2),(Job3),(Job4)) cs (Jobs)
Group by Owner
```

**Note :** This considers those empty's in sample data as `NULL` values in table

Comment: Thank you.  I've never seen "Cross Apply" before.  Definitely want to try this out.  What is the "cs" in that line?

Comment: @shorton - Just a alias name. check the code updated the `Jobs` with alas name

Answer (score 1):

One more option... just for fun is **GROUPING SETS**

You'll get the **Owner/State** level AND the **Owner** Level in one shot

```
Select [Owner]
      ,[State]
      ,JobCount = sum(isnull(sign(Job1),0)+isnull(sign(Job2),0)+isnull(sign(Job3),0)+isnull(sign(Job4),0))
From  YourTable
Group By Grouping Sets ([State],[Owner]),([Owner])
Order By case when [State] is null then 1 else 0 end
```

Returns

```
Owner   State   JobCount
Frank   FL      1
Frank   TN      2
Joe     FL      2
Joe     TN      3
Joe     NULL    5
Frank   NULL    3
```

Comment: Also new to me (grouping sets).  Thank you.